# Is there a way to define the runorder of two different Testng Listeners?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, testng, listeners

I have two testng Listeners. One to create report html files with results of the testrun, and one to write the results in a database. The html files must be available, to write them in the database, so i must control the runorder.

Is there any configuration possibility or a way to let the listeners communicate with each other?
I'm using maven with the listener property in the pom.xml.

Comment: Another option that Cedric had given for my similar problem is here https://groups.google.com/group/testng-dev/browse_thread/thread/29a45cc277e4a2c6.  You can probably do the same, seclude the call to generate html reports and call this code  from both listeners controlling it with a flag.

Answer (score 3):

No. Maybe you could create your own reporter that calls these two in the order you want?