# TestNG @Listeners ordering issue

Tags: testng

I have multiple listeners in my TestNG test class and its using `@Listeners` annotations to load the listeners.

My listeners are dependent each others, so i need to make sure `listener1` is executing before `listener2` always.

I have tried to give the order when we defining the listeners array. but seems like its not consistent. Sometimes `Listener2` is getting called before `Listener1`.

```
@Listeners({ Listener1.class, Listener2.class })
```

It will be helpful if some expertise on a workaround for this issue.

Using `Java1.6/TestNg6.1.1`

Thanks,

Comment: You can refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009741/can-i-order-my-testng-listeners

Answer (score 4):

TestNG does not guarantee `Listeners` order as answered here by author [Is there a way to define the runorder of two different Testng Listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084157/is-there-a-way-to-define-the-runorder-of-two-different-testng-listeners)
So workaround depends on actions which you do in your listeners, but most probably you have to change these logic (merge listeners etc.).