# Can I order my TestNG listeners?

Tags: annotations, testng, listeners

I have a situation where I need to enable/disable tests(using AnnotationTransformer listener) based on the parameter coming from my suite files(using ISuiteListener listener). However, when I try to read the parameters in my suite file before calling AnnotationTransformer, I am not able to do so.

This does not help:

```
<listeners preserve-order="true">
        <listener class name="automation.test.SentinelSuiteListener" />
        <listener class-name="automation.test.AnnotationTransformer" />
</listeners>
```

Also, when I try to implement both these interfaces together, the method for AnnoataionTransformer i.e. transform goes before the onStart() method:

```
public class AnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer, ISuiteListener {

    String currentRunModeInSuite;

    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        currentRunModeInSuite = suite.getParameter("currentRunMode");
    }

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        System.out.println("***Test case under review : " + testMethod.getName());
        for(int i=0; i<annotation.getGroups().length;i++){
            System.out.println(annotation.getGroups()[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(currentRunModeInSuite);
    }  


    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you seen is the expected one because TestNG works step by step.

First, it looks for tests and reads their datas. You can be triggered if you want to change them and it's the goal of `IAnnotationTransformer`.

Then, TestNG runs suite/tests/classes/methods and you can be triggered by that with `ISuiteListener` or else.

What you need is `IMethodInstance` which is called during the run: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors

Fyi, the `<listeners>` node doesn't accept `preserve-order` attribute. See the documentation: http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JulienHerr. With IMethodInstance, I was able to do exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Is there a way, we can use dependsOnMethods or anything similiar with the IMethodInstance? Please suggest, as we have to select some tests to run but those tests have dependencies as well.

Comment: I don't see any solution out-of-the-box, but maybe you can have a multi-step method interceptor: 1/ Extract methods (as before) 2/ Map methods by name 3/ Add depending methods of methods from 1/. http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html#getMethodsDependedUpon-- can help to find dependencies.

Comment: I added an entity to the groups - 
groups = { "followedByMethods:test1,test2"} 
and then parsed this in the MethodInterceptor and sorted the list accordingly. Though is got pretty complex and looked like overkilling.

Comment: It is really beyond me why the design is such that the user cannot use a parameter from suite file in the AnnotationTransfomer. If ordering was required, AnnotationTransformer could have been placed after SentinelSuiteListener.

Comment: By default, the idea behind `suite.xml` is to configure the run (params + enable/disable tests). I don't have the whole picture, but in your case, you should be able to remove the `AnnotationTransformer` and use a specific `suite.xml`. You should create a new question or ask more on the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users